# How WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer work?

Tags: c#, roslyn

As you might know, we can develop some analyzers and code fixes for our CSharp projects based on facilities provided by Roslyn and Visual Studio Integration.
When I develop a code fix to change code syntax tree, It works with `WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer`. For Example change all TypeDeclaration name to Uppercase.

```
public class MyClassCodeFixProvider : CodeFixProvider
{
    private const string title = "MyClassCodeFix";

    public sealed override ImmutableArray<string> FixableDiagnosticIds
    {
        get { return ImmutableArray.Create("MyClassCodeFix"); }
    }

    public sealed override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider()
    {
        return WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;
    }
    public async sealed override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
    {
        var document = context.Document;
        var span = context.Span;
        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;

        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var token = root.FindToken(span.Start);
        if (!token.Span.IntersectsWith(span))
        {
            return;
        }
        Diagnostic diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
        TextSpan diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;
        TypeDeclarationSyntax declaration = root.FindToken(diagnosticSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<TypeDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        var codeChangeForDocument = CodeAction.Create(
                            title: title,
                            //this code works fine
                            createChangedSolution: c => MakeUppercaseAsync(context, declaration, c),
                            equivalenceKey: title);
        context.RegisterCodeFix(codeChangeForDocument, context.Diagnostics);

    }
    private async Task<Solution> MakeUppercaseAsync(CodeFixContext context, TypeDeclarationSyntax typeDecl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var identifierToken = typeDecl.Identifier;
        var newName = identifierToken.Text.ToUpperInvariant();

        var semanticModel = await context.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);
        var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(typeDecl, cancellationToken);

        var originalSolution = context.Document.Project.Solution;
        var optionSet = originalSolution.Workspace.Options;
        var newSolution = await Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(context.Document.Project.Solution, typeSymbol, newName, optionSet, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return newSolution;
    }
}
```

But, when we add some new documents in our code fix, and then we use Code fix across document or project or solution, It doesn't work at all (`WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer` window does not open). But when we call our code fix on one diagnostic, it works perfect.

```
    public sealed override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider()
    {
        return WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;
    }

    public async sealed override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
    {
        var document = context.Document;
        var span = context.Span;
        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;

        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var token = root.FindToken(span.Start);
        if (!token.Span.IntersectsWith(span))
        {
            return;
        }
        Diagnostic diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
        TextSpan diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;
        TypeDeclarationSyntax declaration = root.FindToken(diagnosticSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<TypeDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        var codeChangeForDocument = CodeAction.Create(
                            title: title,
                            //createChangedSolution: c => MakeUppercaseAsync(context.Document, declaration, c),
                            //this code does not work
                            createChangedSolution : c => GenerateDocForSolution(context, declaration, c),
                            equivalenceKey: title);
        context.RegisterCodeFix(codeChangeForDocument, context.Diagnostics);

    }

    private async Task<Solution> GenerateDocForSolution(CodeFixContext context, TypeDeclarationSyntax declaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var model = await context.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);
        ExtractPropFromEntitySyntaxWalker extractor = new ExtractPropFromEntitySyntaxWalker(model);
        extractor.Visit(declaration);

        var currentDoc = context.Document.Project.Documents.SingleOrDefault(doc => doc.Name == string.Format("{0}Auto", declaration.Identifier.Text));
        Document newDoc = null;
        if (currentDoc != null)
        {
            newDoc = currentDoc.WithSyntaxRoot(extractor.NewSyntax);
        }
        else
        {
            newDoc = context.Document.Project.AddDocument(string.Format("{0}Auto", declaration.Identifier.Text),
                                                            extractor.NewSyntax.GetText()
                                                            );
        }

        return newDoc.Project.Solution;
    }
```

As far as I know, `WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer` merges all changes made by all code fixes for all diagnostics across solution, project or document.
Does `WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer` support scenarios such as this?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it may be that the BatchFixer is not smart enough to handle the case when your code fix adds documents, so you may need to write your own fix all provider.

Comment: This is an older question, but the `BatchFixer` only works on [specific types of operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.codefixes.wellknownfixallproviders.batchfixer?view=roslyn-dotnet#remarks). Since the code fix shown here does not use those specific types of code fixes required by `BatchFixer`, they'll just get ignored.